# How can we use Tine 2.0 in our closed source software product, without violating the AGPL?

Tags: licensing, commercial, closed-source, agpl

We develop a closed source product and customers want to add two parts:

- Calendar
- Contacts

[Tine 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tine_2.0) would provide this, but we want to use it as a library.

Since Tine 2.0 uses the AGPL licence, we need to open source our code, if we would use some kind of linking.

How can we use Tine 2.0 in our closed source software product, without violating the AGPL?

The solution I have in mind is this: Our product and Tine 2.0 could communicate over the database. All HTML views get done by our code, and mobile sync stuff gets handled by tine20.

(I would like to open source our product, but my boss does not).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to talk to a lawyer to get a detailed legal opinion on the letter of the law.

That said, using AGPL or GPL code in a closed source application goes against the **spirit** (if not the letter) of the GPL.  The intent is that if you build something that substantially depends on GPL code your code is a derived work and must be distributed under the GPL.

Given that there is a commercial entity behind Tine 2.0 I think they will take narrow view of how it can be integrated with a closed source product. So be prepared for your interpretation to be challenged by them.